# Is autocovariance of a deterministic time series always zero?

Tags: time-series, autocorrelation

Given a process with a deterministic trend such as, $y_t=a+b t+u_t$, where $u_t$ has a constant variance, can you assume the autocovariance to be zero at all times?

Comment: This is not a deterministic time series since it contains the stochastic $u_t$, so your title is misleading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you assume $a$ and $b$ are constant, then you could calculate the autocovariance of the first order as 
$$Cov[y_t, y_{t-1}] = E[(y_t - E[y_t])(y_{t-1} - E[y_{t-1}])]$$

You get $$E[y_t] = E[a + bt + u_t] = a + bt + E[u_t].$$ This means that $y_t - E[y_t] = a + bt + u_t - (a + bt + E[u_t])$ and assuming that for instance $u_t \sim N(0, \sigma^2)$, you have $E[u_t] = 0$.

Thus you end up with
$$ Cov[y_t, y_{t-1}] = E[(u_t)(u_{t-1})]$$
Therefore, if $u_t$ is independently and identically distributed with mean 0, then the autocorrelation will be zero.

Comment: @Richard Since $\hat y_t$ and $E[y_t]$ are both "the expected value of $y_t,$" it is difficult to fathom what you might be objecting to.

Comment: I changed the $\hat{y}_t$ to $E[y_t]$. What do mean exactly by 'what you might be objecting to'?

Comment: Whizkid, as indicated by the initial "@Richard," my comment was replying to an earlier comment that has since been deleted.